# Extend openldap schema

Tags: ldap, schema, extend

I am trying add custom atrributes using the blog.ldif

```
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.5.1.62
  NAME 'imieno'
  DESC 'imie number for device '
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
  SINGLE-VALUE )
```

I tried to add it to ldap using

```
ldapmodify -D "cn=manager,cn=config" -f blogURL.ldif -W
```

I get an error saying

> invalid format (line 7) entry: "cn=schema"

What am i missing? Can anyone give me a sample ldif file to try it out?

Answer (score 1):

The dn should be `cn=schema,cn=config` according to http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html.
The first line of your ldif would become:

```
dn: cn=schema,cn=config
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try that. If i change the dn. I get the error ldap_modify: Invalid syntax (21)
 additional info: attributeTypes: value #0 invalid per syntax   is it something to with spaces... i have given 2 spaces before each line